# Cordova/Phonegap login using PHP, AJAX, Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova

I am using Cordova to build an android app. Now I have trouble with login. I hope you can help me. When clicked on submit button, the form dissappears for a moment and redirect back. Also, when I go to my PHP file URL, the page remains blank. This is my code:

HTML

```
    <div id = "loginform">


        <form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
  var url = window.location.pathname;var filename =      url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 if(localStorage.login=="true" && filename == 'index.html')   {window.location.href = "index.html";}
else if(localStorage.login=="false" && filename != 'index.html'){window.location.href = "index.html";}
</script>
                <p>Vul hier uw inloggegevens in</p>

            <input type = "image" id = "close_login" src = "img/close-button.png" onclick="hidepopup()">
            <input name ="id" type = "text" id = "email" placeholder = "E-mailadres">
            <input name ="pass" type = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "Wachtwoord">
            <input type = "submit" id = "login" onclick ="js/login.js" >

        </form>

    </div>

 </center>
```

JS Login

```
$("#login").click(function(){
var id=$("#id").val();
var pass=$("#pass").val();
var dataString="id="+id+"&pass="+pass+"&login=";
if($.trim(id).length>0 & $.trim(pass).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'https://stopfoodwaste.charlenemacdonald.com/www/login.php',
data: dataString,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
localStorage.login="true";
localStorage.id=id;
window.location.href = "homepage.html";
}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert("Login error");
$("#login").html('Login');
}
}
});
}return false;
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $passw = $_POST['pass'];

 $host = 'charlenemacdonald.com';
 $user = 'userpass (deleted)';
 $pass = 'password (deleted)';

 mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

mysql_select_db('charlenemacdonald_com_StopFoo') or die( 'Error'.     mysql_error() );

  $login=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from Gebruikers where id='$id'          and pass='$passw'")) or 
  die (mysql_error() );


 if(isset($_POST['login']))
 {



 if($login!=0)
 {
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "failed";
 }
 }

 ?>
```

I hope you can help me, because I must overlook something. I am not familiar with JS and JQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Is you code some place public so I can look at it? If not, can you post your entire `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You have taken button type as submit, So once it clicks the submit button it refresh the page as no action related to submit is mention. Try changing button type from submit to button. Then it will call your on click function.

```
    <form>
            <p>Vul hier uw inloggegevens in</p>

        <input name ="id" type = "text" id = "email" placeholder = "E-mailadres">
        <input name ="pass" type = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "Wachtwoord">
        <input type = "button" id = "login" >

    </form>
```

And in your js file add on click in document ready function.

Comment: Can you remove that onClick in button.